# Windows Server Appfabric on windows server 2008 R2 web edition

Tags: windows-server-2008, appfabric

Is there any way to install the Windows Server AppFabric on the windows server 2008 web edition ?

Or at least the WCF hosting enviroment.

What are the supported edition for appfabric ?

Comment: the first part of your question seems to imply you know the answer to the last part.

Comment: I know I cannot install it on web and foundation edition.

Comment: well if you know the answer, why are you asking? This is not a site explaining how to bypass microsoft licensing requirements.

Comment: I'm just confused, I read the system requirements on the download page and there is nothing about the edition restriction. This is uncool. Not everyone can aford a Windows server 2008 enterprise edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think you can't install AppFabric on Server 2008 Web? Comparing the Server 2008 Web overview [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/2008-web.aspx) and the AppFabric requirements [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2#SystemRequirements) I don't see anything that suggests the two aren't compatible.

---

The [rationale](http://twitter.com/ronljacobs/status/25903639754) behind this is that Appfabric is designed for the middle-tier, not the web tier.

So. Accepting that you can't install on Web Server, what are your options?

1. Windows Server 2008, Standard Edition
   So if you want to use AppFabric but you can't afford Enterprise Edition, can you afford Windows 2008 Server Standard Edition. AppFabric will install on it quite happily, and you can install IIS and DNS services on it to replicate what you get in Web Edition. The only thing you won't have is the high availability AppFabric features, but had you been able to install on Web Edition you wouldn't have had that anyway so you're not missing out.
2. AppFabric Client on Web Server, AppFabric Service on Standard Edition
   Kind of an extension of 1. If you have your heart set on using Windows Web Server, you can install the AppFabric client libraries on Web Server, and then run the AppFabric service on a Standard Edition server.
3. Other Distributed Cache
   Could you use one of the other distributed caching setups e.g. [memcached](http://memcached.org/), [SharedCache](http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/), [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)?

Comment: When I was installing AppFabric I got a message "Unsupported Operating System Edition". You can see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637701.aspx .This really bad. The enteprise edition is pretty expensive.

Comment: Having tried it this morning myself I get the same message :-( It's pretty sucky that this restriction isn't mentioned in the AppFabric system requirements.

Comment: Yes, I totaly forgot about the standart editions! But if I run a webserver on the standart edition do I have to have for each visitor a CAL (client access license)?